# Can not read property of undefined JavaScript

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeerror

```
 if (kb.pressed.d) {
        playerList[client.socket.id].img.x += 3;
        characterFrame = cycles.runRight[(Math.floor(Date.now() / 100) % 4)];
    }
   playerList[client.socket.id].img.x += 3;
```

When I run this, the part outside of the if statement throws an error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'img' of undefined) but the same line of code INSIDE the statement gets executed perfectly fine. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Edit: i figured out the problem. `playerList[client.socket.id].img.x += 3;` runs BEFORE it's declared. It's a matter of miliseconds but that's what caused it to throw an error.

Comment: Maybe `playerList` only has a key that matches `client.socket.id` when `kb.pressed.d` is true? You'll have to trace the preceding of the code. We can't really answer this question based on the code you've given us.

Comment: Do you know for sure the part inside the `if` gets executed at all? Did you put a breakpoint there, or some logging?

Comment: Post your `playerList` as well so we can see what it contains

Comment: `if (kb.pressed.d) {
        playerList[client.socket.id].img.x += 3;
        characterFrame = cycles.runRight[(Math.floor(Date.now() / 100) % 4)];
    }
    console.log(client.socket.id);` This worked as expected, it logged a console ID and when i manually pasted `playerList[that_id].img.x += 3;` it worked just fine.